# Using plyr in R to count

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to compute summary statistics for a data file I have. I have seen several articles on similar topics but they didn't quite answer my questions. The data file contains sensitive material so I don't want to share it. But I will use the baseball data set in plyr to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

I am trying to compute a table of summary statistics, and one of the statistics requires making a count on unique elements of a factor variable. So if we use the baseball package for example, how would I go about finding how many teams each player had played for and attaching that to the rest of the dataset (the rest of the dataset being the other summary statistics I have computed on a per player basis)?

```
ddply(baseball, "id", summarise, total_games=sum(g),    
      still_active=ifelse(max(year) ==‌ 2007,"Yes","No"),
      number_teams=as.data.frame(
          with(baseball[!duplicated(baseball$te‌​am)],table(id))))
```

Above is an example, the very last parameter is the one I'm struggling with. How do I find the number of teams each player has been on? I have been trying to use  `as.data.frame(table())`, but have had no success.

Answer (score 2):

Given the example in your comment, you can use the following to compute the number of teams :

```
ddply(baseball,"id",summarise,total_games=sum(g),
      still_active=ifelse(max(year)==2007,"Yes","No"),
      number_teams=length(unique(team)))
```

Which gives :

```
            id total_games still_active number_teams
1    aaronha01        3298           No            3
2    abernte02         681           No            7
3    adairje01        1165           No            4
4    adamsba01         482           No            2
5    adamsbo03        1281           No            4
6    adcocjo01        1959           No            5
7    agostju01         543           No            5
8    aguilri01         730           No            4
9    aguirha01         447           No            4
10   ainsmed01        1078           No            5
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of `data.table` package - it makes this and other requests so much easier, once you grok the syntax:

```
library(data.table)
bb <- data.table(baseball)
bb[, list(
       games = sum(g), 
       teams = length(unique(team)), 
       home.runs = sum(hr), 
       still.active = max(year) == 2007), 
   by = id]
```

results in

```
             id games teams home.runs still.active
   1: ansonca01  2523     3        97        FALSE
   2: forceda01  1029    10         1        FALSE
   3: mathebo01   623     8         1        FALSE
   4: startjo01  1071     6        15        FALSE
   5: suttoez01  1263     4        25        FALSE
  ---                                             
1224: sweenma01  1120     7        42         TRUE
1225: walketo04  1288     7       107         TRUE
1226: witasja01   284     7         0         TRUE
1227: graffto01   974     6        58         TRUE
1228: perezne01  1403     5        64         TRUE
```

One other advantage of `data.table` is that it's often faster since you can sort the data table by setting the key:

```
setkey(bb, id)
```

and after that, every summary operation by this key (or search, or join by...) will be much faster. You can also set key on several columns.